# To check whether my code is correct or not

Tags: java

void addEntry(Integer newEntry) 
throws SimulationException

Adds a new entry to the log. 
Existing entries are shifted along one place in the window accordingly. 
Parameters: 
**newEntry** - the new value to be added to the log

Throws: 
**SimulationException** - if the given value is not in the range 0 to maxEntry, inclusive

how does the code look like ? does it look like this ?

```
public void addEntry(Integer newEntry) throws SimulationException{  

    }
```

Comment: And what is the concrete question?

Comment: -1 See Santiago's Answer

Answer (score 3):

That's fine. Now, you hardly want to log in to Stack Overlflow every time you need to check if some invocation is right :) learn to use:

a) the Java compiler. If you try and compile code with erroneous syntax, the compiler will tell you where you made your mistake! Learn to use and interpret the outputs of the compiler.

b) an advanced Java development environment, such as Eclipse. Actually, I've no idea how can someone code in Java without Eclipse. For me, it's almost part of the language.

Cheers!

Comment: i'd say the same goes for Maven, Idea, Log4J, and lots of other Java-goodies =)

Answer (score 0):

```java
class Square {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int n = 289, r;
        r = sqrt(n);
        if (n==r) {
            System.out.println("Perfect Square");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a Perfect Square");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).